Do browser extensions worsen the position of pages in Google SERP?
Since March, Google also takes into account how quickly the content is loaded for its SERP metrics and the position of the website in the search results. (Announced https://web.dev/blog/inp-cwv-launch?hl=en.)
I run some tests for my website and Devtools reported some mistakes, but it was mistakes created by browser extensions.
Like using XMLHttpRequest insted of fetch(), but this was in third party extension code, not in website code. But extension included that code into website.
So if Chrome sending Core Web Vitals metrics (INP, …) to Google, and Google using it for position in SERP.
So does using extension lowers position of website I am visiting?
Because I guess browser when sending this data using data & time loaded with actual website it's fly by sending, not something like turn off all extensions and then load website again.

Even browser extension effect it, I'd think that those browsers extensions would be slowing down all sites, so your site wouldn't be unfairly slowed by them compared to other sites.
